# Performance of assembly function with multiple RET

Tags: performance, assembly, x86, x86-64, micro-optimization

Does function such as this have negative effect on performance?

```
fn:
cmp rdi, 0
je lbl0
...
ret
lbl0:
...
ret

call fn
```

And this one?

```
fn0:
... ; no ret, fall through
fn1:
...
ret
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fall through is the most efficient thing you can do; it's just normal execution.  The CPU can't even know the difference between "2 different functions" vs. labels within a function; it's all just machine code.  Labels are zero-width, and just give you a way to refer to that address from elsewhere.

From a high level you could look at it as an optimized tailcall of the 2nd function like you'd do with `jmp fn1` instead of `call fn1; ret`, and then of course optimizing away `jmp +0` because jumping to the next instruction is architecturally a `nop`.

---

As for the first one, **that's called "tail duplication" optimization**, where multiple paths out of a function duplicate any necessary cleanup (`pop rbx` or whatever) and a `ret`, instead of running an extra `jmp` to reach a single copy of the cleanup.

Tail duplication costs code footprint (static code size) but results in fewer dynamic instructions executed per call.  It doesn't generally hurt branch prediction; `ret` is predicted by a stack-like predictor that matches `ret` with `call` (i.e. it assumes that `ret` will return to the last `call` that executed.)  As long as this is still true (which it is here), you don't have a problem.  You have multiple ways out of the function, but exactly one of them runs for each call to it.

You can also do loop tail duplication where you branch inside the loop and each side of the branch separately has a `dec ecx / jnz .top_of_loop` (with any necessary `jmp` or whatever outside the loop).